# Trigger Peoplecode from a grid when a row is selected

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

To make a row  selected in a grid we can use this Peoplecode :

```
&rsGriD.getRow(&i).selected =True;
```

**But how we can trigger peoplecode if a row in a grid is selected ?**

There is any field in a grid that represent the CheckBock Select, it is added just by making in Grid properties Multiple Row ( check box) in Row selection Indicator.

Can someone Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that i did , i disabled the standard selection in grid properties and i add a (Y/N) field as checkbox in the grid , and in the FieldChange of this field i do this :

```
If myfield.Value="Y" then

getRow().Selected = true;

/* My specific Pcode */
Else
getRow().Selected = false;
/* My specific Pcode */
end-if;
```

the reason why i do this `getRow().Selected = true;` is to not break the existing code on this Grid.

Hope will help someone.